# Javascript strings wrap

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to find a solution for the following test:
*you should be able to wrap lines at a given number of columns, without breaking words*

the input string is:

```
var inputStrings = [
  'abcdef abcde abc def',
  'abc abc abc',
  'a b c def'
];
```

and the output should be:

```
var outputStrings = [
  'abcdef\nabcde\nabc\ndef',
  'abc\nabc\nabc',
  'a b c\ndef'
];
```

I came up with this jsfiddle that passes 2 out of the 3 tests:
https://jsfiddle.net/ticuclaudiu/yh269rc0/5/

```
function wordWrap(str, cols) {
  var formatedString = '', 
        wordsArray = [];


    wordsArray = str.split(' ');

  for(var i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {

    if(wordsArray.indexOf(wordsArray[i]) === 0) {
        formatedString += wordsArray[i];
    } else {  
        if(wordsArray[i].length > 1) {
            formatedString += '/n' + wordsArray[i];
        } else {
            formatedString +=' ' + wordsArray[i];
        }
    }
  }

  console.log(formatedString);
}

//wordWrap('abcdef abcde abc def', 5);
wordWrap('abc abc abc', 5);
//wordWrap('a b c def', 5);

//'abcdef abcde abc def'    |       'abcdef\nabcde\nabc\ndef',
//'abc abc abc'                     |       'abc\nabc\nabc',        
//'a b c def'                           |       'a b c\ndef'
```

But I can't figure out how to pass the second one ('abc abc abc');

It has to be pure javascript.

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: why is the third item not having \n for all spaces?

Comment: Please show the code **in the question**... placing it in a jsfiddle is not acceptable

Comment: Also, if this is a test, why are you asking us to do it for you?  Surely the point of a test is to prove you can do something yourself?

Comment: This, in the fiddle, cannot be your actual code: `formatedString += '/n'`.

Comment: code added to the question, I'm asking here because I can't find an answer and I tried the entire day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer seems to be:

```
function wordWrap(str, cols) {
    var formatedString = '',
        wordsArray = [];


    wordsArray = str.split(' ');

    formatedString = wordsArray[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
        if (wordsArray[i].length > cols) {
            formatedString += '\n' + wordsArray[i];
        } else {
            if (formatedString.length + wordsArray[i].length > cols) {
                formatedString += '\n' + wordsArray[i];
            } else {
                formatedString += ' ' + wordsArray[i];
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(formatedString);
}

wordWrap('abcdef abcde abc def', 5);
wordWrap('abc abc abc', 5);
wordWrap('a b c def', 5);
```

you can see jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ticuclaudiu/yh269rc0/13/

Comment: This answer passes all three tests, but isn't actually correct. It just puts every word that is positioned in the string after the column width on its own line, so for example `wordWrap('a b c def a b c', 5)` renders lines `a b c`, `def`, `a`, `b`, `c`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do it with regex like this

```
var input = [
  'abcdef abcde abc def',
  'abc abc abc',
  'a b c def'
];
var output = input.map(function(val){
      return val.replace(/(^|[ ])[^ ]{2,}([ ]|$)/g,function(val2){
           return val2.replace(' ','\\n')
      })
 })
console.log(output) // ["abcdef\nabcde\nabc\ndef", "abc\nabc\nabc", "a b c def"]
```

Comment: is not good, it doesn't pass the third test.

Comment: i change the regex expression, it should work now

Comment: Now it fails at test 1. But I managed to find a solution.
I will add a comment below with the solution. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: This fails at test 1. It outputs 'abcdef\nabcde\nabc def'. Additionally, you don't need the double '\\'.